# "Response is not well-formed XML" when calling java Web Service from .NET Console App

Tags: .net, xml, web-services

I am trying to call a java based web service from a .net console app.  I am overriding the GetWebResponse() method, however it returns "Response is not well-formed XML."  I do have xml back, just trying to get rid of this error.  Here are the highlights of the code-

```
 Public Class CureWebServiceHelper
Inherits FXRates2013.CureWebService.RatesWebServiceV2

Public Shared Function ConnectToWS(ByVal dataService As System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebClientProtocol) As Boolean

    Try
        Dim wsURL As String, wsUserId As String, wsPwd As String, wsDomain As String
        With ConfigurationManager.AppSettings
            wsURL = .Get("CureWebServiceURL").ToString

            wsUserId = .Get("CureWebServiceUserId").ToString
            wsPwd = .Get("CureWebServiceUserPwd").ToString

            wsDomain = "ad-ent"
        End With

        dataService.Url = wsURL

        Dim Creds As New System.Net.CredentialCache()
        Dim netCred As New System.Net.NetworkCredential(wsUserId, wsPwd)
        Creds.Add(New Uri(dataService.Url), "Basic", netCred)
        dataService.Credentials = Creds      'attach password. 

        Return True

    Catch ex As Exception
        Return False
    End Try

End Function

Protected Overloads Overrides Function GetWebResponse(ByVal the_webRequest As WebRequest) As WebResponse

    Dim WR As WebResponse
    WR = MyBase.GetWebResponse(the_webRequest)

    Dim sr As New IO.StreamReader(WR.GetResponseStream)

    Dim ResultStr = sr.ReadToEnd

    'Populate this XML instead. 
    Dim ReturnXML = ResultStr

    Return MyBase.GetWebResponse(the_webRequest)

End Function
End Class
```

and in my main module-

```
     Sub Main()
    Dim strXML As String = ""

    Using webService As New CureWebServiceHelper
        CureWebServiceHelper.ConnectToWS(webService)

        Dim WSResponse As String
        Call webService.getClosedRatesAsXml("MO_London", "12/02/2013", True, FXRates2013.CureWebService.wsRateTypeEnum.Spot, True)

    End Using


End Sub
```

How can i get rid of the error?  I have no control over the web service itself, so nothing i can do there.

EDIT:  Here is the xml-

```
 <soap:Envelope  xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
 <soap:Body>    
   <ns1:getClosedRatesAsXmlResponse xmlns:ns1="http://fx.wachovia.net">    
    <ns2:ClosedFXRatesAsXml xmlns:ns2="http://fx.wachovia.net"><OfficialClosing>
<ClosingSetName>MO_London</ClosingSetName>
<CloseDate>20131202</CloseDate>
<Status>CLOSED</Status>
<FXRate>
    <NumeratorCcy>USD</NumeratorCcy>
    <DenominatorCcy>SVC</DenominatorCcy>
    <Tenor>SPOT</Tenor>
    <Type>Spot</Type>
    <Rate>8.7475</Rate>
</FXRate>
</OfficialClosing>
</ns2:ClosedFXRatesAsXml></ns1:getClosedRatesAsXmlResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: It would help to see what the actual XML looks like.

Comment: *I have no control over the web service itself, so nothing i can do there.* You can always insert your own strings into the XML before parsing it.

Comment: I added the xml above.  Thanks

Comment: Maybe treat it as a POX service? http://poxnet.codeplex.com/